# Issue with datetime parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, localization

When I tried to parse the `"2017-09-25T11:06:55+00:00"` date string using TryParse method, I get the following output:

```
{9/25/2017 7:06:55 AM}
```

So, it's looks like 11 a.m. is getting converted into 7 a.m. Not sure why is this happening this? Is it because of `+00:00??`
What do I need to do so that parsed Datetime output is same: i.e. `{9/25/2017 11:06:55 AM}` ?

I tried using Current locale/culture and DateTime Styles. Assume Local but no luck.
(Note: I'm in the eastern time-zone)

Thanks.

Comment: That's a UTC timestamp, what you get is likely your local time.  It's usually best to keep all dates in code and DB in UTC and just use local time for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the UTC timezone (+00:00), but apparently, you or your PC is in -04:00 timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use DateTimeOffset, then I tend to prefer it. You get time zone info preserved, and you have access to both local and UTC datetime properties off this object.

```
        var dt = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2017-09-25T11:06:55+00:00");
        Console.WriteLine(dt.DateTime);         // 9-25 at 11:06
        Console.WriteLine(dt.UtcDateTime);      // 9-25 at 11:06
        Console.WriteLine(dt.LocalDateTime);    // 9-25 at 07:06
```

If you know you're always going to be dealing with UTC, you can just parse by adjusting to universal like so:

```
        var dt = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-25T11:06:55+00:00", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        Console.WriteLine(dt); // 9-25 at 11:06
```

Comment: Thanks Trio.No, its not always going to be UTC.So will the following code be ok: DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal;
      const string utcIdenfitifier = "+00:00";
        if (date.Contains(utcIdenfitifier))
        {
            styles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal;
        }
             


        if (DateTime.TryParse(date, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, styles,  out retVal))
        {
        return retVal;
        }

Comment: Similarly, you can use something like this:var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2017-09-25T11:06:55+00:00"); return dto.Offset == TimeSpan.Zero ? dto.UtcDateTime : dto.LocalDateTime;

Answer (score 0):

When you parse it initially it's the correct value, it's just now adjusted to be in your timezone. You can force it with `ToUniversalTime` :

```cs
DateTime.Parse("2017-09-25T11:06:55+00:00").ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt")
```

output

```cs
"2017/09/25 11:06:55 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse correctly UTC DateTime and to have 9/25/2017 11:06:55 AM instead of 9/25/2017 7:06:55 AM. +00:00 is not correct UTC format, you need to change it to "2017-09-25T11:06:55z".

[Here is working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yjWN3F)